# I want to generate a report from Bugzilla

Tags: bug-report, bugzilla

I want to generate a bug report from Bugzilla, which should be consist of following status

1. Confirmed
2. In progress
3. Verified and Closed

So how I can generate the report with the mentioned status?

[image: Please see report format]

Comment: Can you please rephrase or elaborate your question?

Comment: OK, you have my permission to do so (if you wanted one) :-)

Comment: I want report for multiple bugs

Comment: Can you please rephrase or re-write this so it's in the form of a question? As is, it is not clear what you are asking for help with.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and save a query, then export it.